# Spring Boot RestTemplate get Cookie from Callback

Tags: java, spring-boot, callback, token, response-headers

I would like to retrieve a jwt token, using Spring RestTemplate, from a callback that is a redirect URL from a login URL.

I have been able to connect to the login URL, I have been able to follow the redirect link to the callback, but I have not been able to retieve the token that is stored in the reponse header of the callback.

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = my_login_url;

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add(my_login);
map.add(my_password);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .build();
factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                String.class);

// OUCH !! response does not contain the token I'm trying to retrieve !! The token is in the header of the callback !!
```

Could anybody help me understand how to access the header of the callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I was able to find a way to retrieve that token, that seems more like a hack to me than an actual solution.
The idea is that the apache HttpClient contains a cookie store with just the token I need. Unfortunately, HttpClient does not have any getters, only `execute` methods, and I'm already on RestTemplates.
However, it is possible to pass a Cookie Store as a parameter while building the HttpClient instance. That Cookie Store will be filled while posting the authentication request.

The final version of the code looks like that:

```java
public void getCookies() {

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String url = my_login_url;

 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

 MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
 map.add("username_key", my_user);
 map.add("password_key", my_password);

 HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

 final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new 
 HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
 CookieStore basicCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
 final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .setDefaultCookieStore(basicCookieStore)
                .build();
 factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
 restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);

 restTemplate.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                String.class);

 Cookie cookie  = basicCookieStore.getCookies().stream()
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(url));
 System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
}
```

Notice that I am not even interested in the response of the `restTemplate.exchange` query.

Comment: @Towfiqul Islam, THX for your edit. It helped clarify my post! However, I don't think there is a need for wrapping the code in a method. I don't think it helps in any way, especially that it has no return value. Could you please remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
```

(While the client sends the cookies it has via the "Cookie" header, the server sends cookies to set with a "Set-Cookie" header.)

This returns a list because each cookie will be in an extra header with the same name.

Comment: There are several issues in your answer: first, this gives the headers of the response (à priori) when I said I need to access the header of the redirect response; second, it's not `ResponseEntity.SET_COOKIE`, but `HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE`

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but even after reading your question another two times, only with the help of your comment I was able to understand your real need. But so my wrong answer helped at least me to understand the problem correctly ;) For the wrong constant: fully blame on me, I'll fix that of course!

Comment: Sorry about that. My use case is actually a bit tricky I admit. It's even trickier using Springboot because part of the code is hidden in the Configuration class and everything is singleton. Anyways, just to let you know, I still got you a "-1" on your answer because it really does not answer my question. But I grant you my full gratitude for trying and being so comprehensive, because I must admit my comment was written a bit hastily and was kind of harsh...